# Obtaining a sum of values for each unique key in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a list of keys, each associated with a numeric value. I want to run an SQL query to list each distinct keys in one column and the sum of all values that have that distinct key in another. This process is identical to first selecting individual

```
  key   |   val
   1    |    4
   2    |    2
   1    |    6
   3    |    7
   2    |   10
```

would return:

```
  key   |   sum
   1    |    10
   2    |    12
   3    |    7
```

I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT key as ukey, SUM(value) as sum from table
```

But that doesn't work. Is there a query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT key, SUM(value) as sum FROM table GROUP BY key`

Here is reference from mysql:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html